# issue while creating VM instance using python code in GCP

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to write a code which will read values from excel file and will create VMs in Google Cloud. I am facing problem at two locations, while creating tags if I use 'items': [tag] or while creating service account scope it starts giving me error.

```
import os, json
import googleapiclient.discovery
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import csv

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('G:/python/json/mykids-280210.json')
compute = googleapiclient.discovery.build('compute', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

def create_instance(compute, vm_name, image_project, image_family, machinetype, startupscript, zone, network,
                          subnet, project, scope, tag):
    # Get the latest Debian Jessie image.
    image_response = compute.images().getFromFamily(
        project=image_project, family=image_family).execute()
    source_disk_image = image_response['selfLink']

    # Configure the machine
    machine_type = "zones/" + zone + "/machineTypes/" + machinetype
    startup_script = startupscript

    config = {
        'name': vm_name,
        'machineType': machine_type,

        'description': 'This VM was created with python code',

        'tags': {
            'items': ['external', 'home', 'local']              #'items': [tag] <~~~~~~~~~~~
        },

        'deletionProtection': False,

        'labels': {'env': 'dev', 'server': 'mytower', 'purpose': 'personal'},

        # Specify the boot disk and the image to use as a source.
        'disks': [
            {
                'boot': True,
                'autoDelete': True,
                'initializeParams': {
                    'sourceImage': source_disk_image,
                }
            }
        ],

        # Specify a network interface with NAT to access the public
        # internet.
        'networkInterfaces': [{
            'network': 'global/networks/' + network,
            'subnetwork': 'regions/us-central1/subnetworks/' + subnet,
            'accessConfigs': [
                {'type': 'ONE_TO_ONE_NAT', 'name': 'External NAT'}
            ]
        }],

        # Allow the instance to access cloud storage and logging.
        'serviceAccounts': [{
            'email': 'default',
            'scopes': [
                #'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write'
                #scope                          # scope      <~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            ]
        }],
        'scheduling': {
            "preemptible": True
        },

        # Metadata is readable from the instance and allows you to
        # pass configuration from deployment scripts to instances.
         'metadata': {
            'items': [{
        # Startup script is automatically executed by the
        # instance upon startup.
                'key': 'startup-script',
                'value': startup_script
            }]
         }
    }

    return compute.instances().insert(
        project=project,
        zone=zone,
        body=config).execute()
# [END create_instance]

with open('vms.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    data = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in data:
        vm_name = row['vm_name']
        image_project = row['image_project']
        image_family = row['image_family']
        machinetype = row['machinetype']
        startupscript = row['startupscript']
        zone = row['zone']
        network = row['network']
        subnet = row['subnet']
        project = row['project']
        scope = row['scopes']
        tag = row['tags']

        print(create_instance(compute, vm_name, image_project, image_family, machinetype, startupscript, zone, network,
                          subnet, project, scope, tag))
    csvfile.close()
```

error when use scope variable

```
G:\python\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe G:/python/pythonProject/read-excel-gcp/vm/create_vm.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\python\pythonProject\read-excel-gcp\vm\create_vm.py", line 100, in <module>
    print(create_instance(compute, vm_name, image_project, image_family, machinetype, startupscript, zone, network,
  File "G:\python\pythonProject\read-excel-gcp\vm\create_vm.py", line 79, in create_instance
    return compute.instances().insert(
  File "G:\python\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 134, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "G:\python\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 915, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/mykids-280210/zones/us-central1-a/instances?alt=json returned "One or more of the service account scopes are invalid: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write',  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write''". Details: "One or more of the service account scopes are invalid: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write',  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write''">

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I get a similar error when I use tag variable.

I have # the value the way I am passing in the above code.

Below is my csv file details

```
vm_name,image_project,image_family,machinetype,startupscript,zone,network,subnet,project,scopes,tags
python-vm1,debian-cloud,debian-9,e2-micro,G:/python/json/startup-script.sh,us-central1-a,myvpc,subnet-a,mykids-280210,"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write',  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write'","external', 'home', 'local'"
python-vm2,debian-cloud,debian-9,e2-micro,G:/python/json/startup-script.sh,us-central1-a,myvpc,subnet-a,mykids-280210,"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write',  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write'","external', 'home', 'local'"
```

I am not sure that when the value are passed directly it works, but when passing the value through variable, it fails.

I have marked the problem area with <~~~~~~~~~~~~

Please suggest if anyone understands the issue.

Comment: For your previous questions, are all of the answers provided wrong? https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: No all the answers were not incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

@d.s can you try changing your scope format to something like this:

```
 'serviceAccounts': [
 {
   'email': 'default'
   'scopes':[
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.write',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write']}]
```

The listed scopes are the default scopes that you will need for an instance. I think the problem you are facing is you where trying to only list two scopes which are not enough to allow you to deploy your instance.

Comment: @d.s, the answer helped you to solve your inquiry?

Comment: @Elisius : Thanks for your reply. I actually want to pass the values using variable. This means the value will be read from a excel file. Passing the values the way you said will work. My problem is how to pass the value dynamically by reading the excel file.

Comment: @ErickSilverio: The answer didn't helps me as the requirement is to use the variable. Directly passing the value works perfectly.